# Creating a table with sidebars and dots on the right

Tags: tables

I was wondering if LaTeX enables you to create something like the figure attached. I know how to make the table on the left, but is there a way to replicate the bars on the right so that if a user click on a dot or the formula at the bottom, it will be sent to a specific section?

Here a snippet of my code for the table

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        Literature review and collections of Ui & Text & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
        ~ & Text & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
        ~ & Text & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
        ~ & Text & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome. // As I understand it, your question has two parts: a) does pdf provide a hoover feature, like webpages do? b) can Latex compile this way?

Comment: You can build something similar in beamer, exploiting its navigation feature. However, in a text I find such things distracting and almost , in the sense of unwillingness, to read

Comment: Hi! hovering was the wrong term. I meant click which I know that it is possible in LaTeX. My question is more how to create the bars on the right and having a table on the left

Comment: You could use `tcolorbox` with a customized right border. See the last box of p. 200 of the [package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox), for example. If you would like to have a complete answer, please add a minimal example of your code.

Comment: thanks for the pointer to `tcolorbox` I did not know it. I have update the question with a very minimal snippet of my table

Comment: @Ibrahim, thank you for the code update. However, can you please turn it into a MWE, e.g. via this procedure/checklist: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790 ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, these are not really tables. But even if they are, I'd just use Ti*k*Z for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, matrix}

\tikzset{
    large box/.style={
        draw,
        text width={\linewidth-5cm},
        text depth=#1,
        align=left,
        prefix after command={
            \pgfextra{\tikzset{
                label position={
                    left
                },
                every label/.style={
                    font=\bfseries\scriptsize,
                    rotate=90,
                    anchor=south
                }}
            }
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[
    large box=4cm, 
    label={Literature review and collections of UIs}
] (box a) {
    \ul{Text} \\ 
    Text 
};

\node[
    large box=3cm, 
    below=of box a,
    label={Community Workshop}
] (box b) {
    \ul{Text} \\ 
    Text 
};

\node[
    large box=3cm, 
    below=of box b,
    label={Computational Analysis}
] (box c) {
    \ul{Text} \\ 
    Text 
};

\node[
    large box=3cm, 
    below=of box c,
    label={Online User Studies}
] (box d) {
    \ul{Text} \\ 
    Text 
};

\node[
    matrix of math nodes, 
    below right=5mm of box d,
    execute at begin node=\strut,
    every node/.append style={
        inner ysep=0pt
    }
] (fn) {
    f( & , & , & , & )= \\
};

\foreach \n/\c in {1/red, 2/green, 3/blue, 4/violet} {
    \draw[\c!50] 
        (box a.north east -| fn-1-\n.east) -- 
        (fn-1-\n.north east);
    \draw[\c!50, ultra thick] 
        (fn-1-\n.north east) -- 
        (fn-1-\n.south east); 
    \draw[yellow!50, rounded corners]
        (fn-1-\n.south east) -- 
        +(0,-0.25) -| 
        (fn-1-5.south east);
}
\draw[yellow!50] 
    (box a.north east -| fn-1-5.east) -- 
    (fn-1-5.north east);
\draw[yellow!50, ultra thick] 
    (fn-1-5.north east) -- 
    (fn-1-5.south east); 

\foreach \b/\d in {%
    a/{1/red,2/green,4/violet,5/yellow},%
    b/{1/red,2/green,3/blue},%
    c/{5/yellow},%
    d/{1/red,2/green,3/blue}%
} {
    \foreach \n/\c in \d {
        \fill[\c!50] 
            (box \b.center -| fn-1-\n.east) circle[radius=2pt];
    }
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Lower right part zoomed in:

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for the detailed solution. I was able to adapt multiple parameters and make the text inside the box clickable. But I ma struggling to reduce the space between the different box. How can I reduce it?

Comment: @Ibrahim I wasn't sure how you wanted to make things "clickable", so I did not add this feature in my MWE. You can adjust the distance between the boxes by changing `below=of box a` etc. to something like: `below=10pt of box a` (or whatever distance you want). You need to change this for all boxes, of course.

Comment: don't worry your solution is great and I am learning a lot about LaTeX. To have a caption and label I have wrap everything in a figure, is right or there is a better way to have these two things?

Comment: @Ibrahim A `figure` (or `table`) environment is a so-called floating environment that is placed by LaTeX automatically at the top or at the bottom of a page or at a separate page. If you want this, and only then, you should use a `figure` (or `table`) environment. In any other case, that is, if you want the figure or table at a specific position in your document, don't use such floating environments. In order to have caption and label without using a floating environment, you could use the `\captionof` command provided by the `caption` package.

Answer (score 1):

A starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
  enhanced,
  frame hidden, interior hidden,
  top=0mm, bottom=0mm, boxsep=0mm,
  finish={%
    \draw[yellow] (frame.north east) -- node[fill=yellow, circle]{} (frame.south east);
    \draw[purple] ([xshift=-5mm]frame.north east) -- node[fill=purple, circle]{} ([xshift=-5mm]frame.south east);
    \draw[blue] ([xshift=-10mm]frame.north east) -- node[fill=blue, circle]{} ([xshift=-10mm]frame.south east);
    },
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
        Literature review and collections of Ui & Text & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
        ~ & Text & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
        ~ & Text & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
        ~ & Text & ~ & ~ & ~ & ~ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]